# Webstorm shows unresolved variable when Typescript has no issues

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 7.0.2 with tsc 0.9.1.1. Webstorm is showing code in red, and shows a number of errors in a tooltip when I move my mouse over the red text `ISystem` below.

```
/// <reference path="launcher-system.ts" />
module Launcher {
  export class SystemStub implements Launcher.ISystem { // ISystem shows as red
  ....
  }
...
}
```

`launcher-system.ts` has the following content:

```
module Launcher {
  export interface ISystem {
  ...
  }
}
```

But there are no errors output from tsc. And, I can click on the red text of `ISystem`, and Webstorm takes me to where `Launcher.ISystem` is defined, in another file.

The tooltip shows four **Unresolved variable** errors.

- Unresolved variable ISystem
- Unresolved variable ISystemm
- Unresolved variable ISystemmm
- Unresolved variable ISystemmmm

The multitude of errors is due to me messing about to see what would happen if I intentionally caused an error by trying to implement an interface that I knew did not exist (e.g. I know for sure that ISystemmmm is not a valid).

I do not know why Webstorm seems to keep a history of errors. But while I know that the misspellings are valid errors, they are history ... why is Webstorm still showing these?

And, how can I fix Webstorm of the one error message, that is not a valid error (e.g. ISystem)?

Comment: confusing : *three of these are valid errors, as I was testing what would happen when I put in an intentional error,*

Comment: @basarat I've added more details to my posting, as it was confusing.

Comment: the same code doesn't show up any errors for me (WebStorm 7.0.2). There must be something else in your code that causes the problem (or this is a 'broken caches' issue). If invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches) doesn't help, can you attach a sample project that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having to make a few assumptions as you haven't shown a complete working example of the issue.

My guess would be that you may have missed off the `export` keyword from the interface? If you leave out the `export` keyword, `ISystem` wouldn't exist on `Launcher`.

First File

```
module Launcher {
    export interface ISystem {

    }
}
```

Second File

```
module Launcher {
      export class SystemStub implements Launcher.ISystem {

      }
}
```

Comment: `ISystem` does have an export, exactly as you have shown above in First File. Your two code blocks above are exactly what I already have.

Comment: In that case, it seems there is a bug in WebStorm as this is valid TypeScript. You should be able to raise it on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23TypeScript+%23{WebStorm+%2F+IntelliJ+Web}

Comment: How typical ... I try and create a simple test case to submit the 'bug' to Jetbrains, and WebStorm doesn't show any errors. It must be something else I've done as the simple case you describe above works fine.